# Fast check if an object will be successfully instantiated in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection, static-code-analysis

How can I check if an object will be successfully instantiated with the given argument, without actually creating the instance?

Actually I'm only checking (didn't tested this code, but should work fine...) the number of *required* parameters, ignoring types:

```php
// Filter definition and arguments as per configuration
$filter = $container->getDefinition($serviceId);
$args   = $activeFilters[$filterName];

// Check number of required arguments vs arguments in config
$constructor = $reflector->getConstructor();

$numRequired  = $constructor->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
$numSpecified = is_array($args) ? count($args) : 1;

if($numRequired < $numSpecified) {
    throw new InvalidFilterDefinitionException(
        $serviceId,
        $numRequired,
        $numSpecified
    );
}
```

**EDIT**: `$constructor` can be `null`...

Comment: It's PHP, as you use Reflection, it's clear that it is PHP 5. If you are concerned about a *specific* PHP 5 version, use the tag of that PHP version - but I don't see that you need that for your question. -- Have you seen http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionparameter.php ?

Comment: @hakre fine, sorry for reverting your edits!

Comment: You can hardly know whether an instantiation will succeed without executing the code. There could be an `if (rand()) throw new Exception` in there, which makes it impossible to determine without running the code.

Comment: @deceze good point. At least I need a static check...

Comment: @deceze I want to cut the keyboard cable of anyone who writes that in any application.

Comment: @Lusitanian LOL. Sure, just making the extreme point that whether an object instantiation succeeds or not depends on runtime information which are impossible to determine without running the code. It doesn't have to be `rand`. In fact, it better not be...

Comment: Here is the problem: I'm writing a reusable part of code, allowing you to define a chain of filters, using a configuration file (Sf2). I'll try to catch a possible mismatch between config arguments and filter class ones. A good example of this would be a "signature" filter, adding a text before sending a message.

Comment: @deceze I totally got the point you were making, just wanted to make a little light of it :P

Comment: This question is basically asking for the code for a full dependency injection container. This problem is much more complicated than what the OP suggests. The only good answer will be a wall of code. You probably need to narrow the focus of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you simply cannot determine if a set of arguments will allow error-free instantiation of a constructor. As commenters have mentioned above, there's no way to know for sure if a class can be instantiated with a given argument list because there are runtime considerations that cannot be known without actually attempting
instantiation.

However, there is value in *trying* to instantiate a class from a list of constructor arguments. The most obvious use-case for this sort of operation is a configurable Dependency Injection Container (DIC). Unfortunately, this is a much more complicated operation than the OP suggests.

We need to determine for each argument in a supplied definition array whether or not it matches specified type-hints from the constructor method signature (if the method signature *actually has* type-hints). Also, we need to resolve how to treat default argument values. Additionally, for our code to be of any real use we need to allow the specification of "definitions" ahead of time for instantiating a class. A sophisticated treatment of the problem will also involve a pool of reflection objects (caching) to minimize the performance impact of repeatedly reflecting things.

Another hurdle is the fact that there's no way to access the type-hint of a reflected method parameter without calling its `ReflectionParameter::getClass` method and subsequently instantiating a reflection class from the returned class name (if `null` is returned the param has no type-hint). This is where caching generated reflections becomes particularly important for any real-world use-case.

The code below is a severely stripped-down version of my own string-based recursive dependency injection container. It's a mixture of pseudo-code and real-code (if you were hoping for free code to copy/paste you're out of luck). You'll see that the code below matches the associative array keys of "definition" arrays to the parameter names in the constructor signature.

The real code can be found over at the relevant [github project page](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Auryn/wiki).

```
class Provider {

    private $definitions;

    public function define($class, array $definition) {
        $class = strtolower($class);
        $this->definitions[$class] = $definition;
    }

    public function make($class, array $definition = null) {
        $class = strtolower($class);

        if (is_null($definition) && isset($this->definitions[$class])) {
            $definition = $this->definitions[$class];
        }

        $reflClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
        $instanceArgs = $this->buildNewInstanceArgs($reflClass);


        return $reflClass->newInstanceArgs($instanceArgs);
    }

    private function buildNewInstanceArgs(
        ReflectionClass $reflClass,
        array $definition
    ) {
        $instanceArgs = array();


        $reflCtor = $reflClass->getConstructor();

        // IF no constructor exists we're done and should just
        // return a new instance of $class:
        // return $this->make($reflClass->name);
        // otherwise ...

        $reflCtorParams = $reflCtor->getParameters();

        foreach ($reflCtorParams as $ctorParam) {
            if (isset($definition[$ctorParam->name])) {
                $instanceArgs[] = $this->make($definition[$ctorParam->name]);
                continue;
            }

            $typeHint = $this->getParameterTypeHint($ctorParam);

            if ($typeHint && $this->isInstantiable($typeHint)) {
                // The typehint is instantiable, go ahead and make a new
                // instance of it
                $instanceArgs[] = $this->make($typeHint);
            } elseif ($typeHint) {
                // The typehint is abstract or an interface. We can't
                // proceed because we already know we don't have a 
                // definition telling us which class to instantiate
                throw Exception;
            } elseif ($ctorParam->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
                // No typehint, try to use the default parameter value
                $instanceArgs[] = $ctorParam->getDefaultValue();
            } else {
                // If all else fails, try passing in a NULL or something
                $instanceArgs[] = NULL;
            }
        }

        return $instanceArgs;
    }

    private function getParameterTypeHint(ReflectionParameter $param) {
        // ... see the note about retrieving parameter typehints
        // in the exposition ...
    }
    private function isInstantiable($class) {
        // determine if the class typehint is abstract/interface
        // RTM on reflection for how to do this
    }
}
```